# If Car is a subtype of Vehicle, why is Vehicle->void considered a subtype of Car->void?

Tags: inheritance, functional-programming, language-agnostic, covariance, contravariance

Reading [a fundamental paper](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/Inheritance.A4.pdf) about inheritance, I am unable to understand the reasoning shown below. Apparently it is correct as contravariance does work, I would just like to understand the reasoning.
First, it is shown that:

- If a function returns **Car**, then it is a subtype of function returning **Vehicle**. That is because all vehicles are also cars. (Covariance of return types).
- If a function takes **Vehicle**, then it is a *subtype* of a function that takes **Car** because  "*In general every function on vehicles is also a function on
  cars.*"
  I cannot understand the explanation  of this inversion, so I am showing this below:
  [image]

**My naive interpretation:**

As functions on ALL vehicles will work on ALL cars, then the function taking Vehicle is a subtype of function taking Car because the set of functions of Vehlice is smaller - Car can have more functions.

Comment: All Cars are Vehicles, but not all Vehicles are Cars (C <= V). All functions that operate on Vehicles can operate on Cars, but not all functions of Cars can operate on Vehicles (f(V) <= f(C)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about covariance and contravariance of functions, and I think it will help for your understanding if we map some of the language-agnostic symbolic relationships in the paper to actual code. In C++, the function being discussed here would be:

```
int GetSpeedOf(Vehicle vehicle);
```

*Subtype* must be understood in terms of [Liskov-substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); if a function is expecting any type of animal, you can give it a cat and everything should work fine, but the opposite is not the case; a function requiring a cat could not work on any type of animal.

Assuming you understand that it is possible to pass a Car to the GetSpeedOf function, now we will address the more complicated case of functions accepting functions, which brings contravariance into the picture.

The following CarWrapper has a private Car which it will do stuff to, using a function supplied from outside. That function must work for Cars. So if you give a function which works more generally for all Vehicles, that's fine.

```
#include <functional>

class Vehicle { };
class Car : public Vehicle { };

class CarWrapper
{
    Car car;
    typedef std::function<auto(Car) -> void> CarCallback;
    CarCallback functionPtr;

public:
    void PassCallback(CarCallback cb)
    {
        functionPtr = cb;
    }

    void DoStuff()
    {
        functionPtr(car);
    }
};

void Works(Vehicle v){}

int main() {
    CarWrapper b;
    b.PassCallback(&Works);
}
```

So, the PassCallback function is expecting type CarCallback ("Car -> void" in your paper), but we give it a subtype, "Vehicle -> void", because the type of "&Works" is actually `std::function<auto(Vehicle) -> void>`. Hence "If a function takes Vehicle, then it is a subtype of a function that takes Car". This is possible because all of the operations that the "Works" function will do, must also be possible on what is actually passed in - a car.

A use-case of this, is that the Works function could also be passed to a BoatWrapper class, which expects a function operating on boats. We can give a subtype of that functiontype, "Vehicle -> void", knowing that all operations in the actual passed function must also be available on the Boat passed to it, since Boat is a subtype of Vehicle, and our actual function only uses the more general Vehicle'ness of the parameter to operate.

Covariance, on the other hand, operates on the return type; if the CarWrapper class expected a callback that generates a Car for us, we would not be able to pass in a Vehicle-generating function, because then CarWrapper would not be able to use the result in car-specific ways.

If we had a function expecting a Vehicle generator though, we would be able to give it a Car Generator or a Boat Generator; hence (void -> Car) is a subtype of (void -> Vehicle) iff Car is a subtype of Vehicle.

Covariance implies that the subtype relationship stays in the same direction, 
so we can keep sticking in another function application, and still the "Car side" will be a subtype of the "Vehicle side", i.e.:

```
Car is a subtype of Vehicle means that:
(void -> Car) is a subtype of (void -> Vehicle) - as in the code sample above
(void -> (void -> Car)) is a subtype of (void -> (void -> Vehicle))
(void -> (void -> (void -> Car))) is a subtype of (void -> (void -> (void -> Vehicle)))
```

What this means is that if we expected a VehicleFactoryFactoryFactory, we should be satisfied when given a CarFactoryFactoryFactory:

```
#include <functional>

class Vehicle { };
class Car : public Vehicle { };

typedef std::function<auto() -> Vehicle> VehicleFactory;
typedef std::function<auto() -> VehicleFactory> VehicleFactoryFactory;
typedef std::function<auto() -> VehicleFactoryFactory> VehicleFactoryFactoryFactory;

void GiveMeAFactory(VehicleFactoryFactoryFactory factory)
{
    Vehicle theVehicle = factory()()();
}

typedef std::function<auto() -> Car> CarFactory;
typedef std::function<auto() -> CarFactory> CarFactoryFactory;
typedef std::function<auto() -> CarFactoryFactory> CarFactoryFactoryFactory;

Car ActualCarCreateFunc() { return Car(); }
CarFactory CarFactoryCreateFunc() { return &ActualCarCreateFunc; }
CarFactoryFactory CarFactoryFactoryCreateFunc() { return &CarFactoryCreateFunc; }

int main() {
    GiveMeAFactory(&CarFactoryFactoryCreateFunc);
}
```

With contravariance of the parameter types, the relationship inverts with each function application.

```
Car is a subtype of Vehicle means that:
(Vehicle -> void) is a subtype of (Car -> void)
((Car -> void) -> void) is a subtype of ((Vehicle -> void) -> void)
(((Vehicle -> void) -> void) -> void) is a subtype of (((Car -> void) -> void) -> void)
```

In the case of contravariance, it is very difficult to understand this in intuitive terms. That's why my CarWrapper only attempts to explain it for a single application of the rule, while the CarFactory example contains three applications of covariance.

Comment: Thank you, it did help me but I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that part of Void(Vehicle) being a subtype of void(Car). Ideally in simple terms as in the comment under my original question.

Comment: I think there is mistake in your last paragraph - Car->Void is not a subtype of Vehicle->void.

Comment: Correct; I had to draw it out on paper to see how multiple applications of contravariance should work. Hopefully it is clearer now that I have it on multiple lines. I also added a bit more plain English after the first code sample. Hopefully if you think about what would go into these functions, you will understand why it intuitively makes sense that the Works function is valid when actually a function operating on Cars was requested by the signature of PassCallback.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added my own answer (as a colleague of mine explained to me in simple words) but of course I leave your answer as it provides a lot of details and implementation examples.